# error while calling asmx file through jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services, asmx

When i am trying to access the services in the same solution the webservice is returning me the result. But when i upload this webservice and trying to access then is giving the error.

```
  var _postData = '{lat:"42.28684519999999",lang:"-83.05254932"}';
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://geo.xyz.com/Service.asmx/GetGeoLocationListByLatLang',
            data: _postData,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
                //                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {

                //                        alert(i);
                //                    });
                //Result(data);
                //                    alert(data.d);
                //                    var obj = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                //                    alert(obj);
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert(request.responseText);
                alert(error);
                alert(status);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are violating the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction that's built-in browsers and which prevents you from sending cross domain AJAX requests. Here's a [nice guide](http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide) which covers different possible workarounds. But since you need to use POST your choices are very limited at this stage. I guess that a server side proxy on your domain serving as a bridge and delegating the call to the remote domain would be the best solution.

Comment: thnx but do you have any example..I read the link but but didn't get the result. in yui it is saying that EOF error...